# list parallelization in for cycle in databricks

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, databricks, azure-databricks

i've recently started to look into parallelization. I got this code that runs on databricks and it's workflow is:

1. import of lot of tables from azure blob storage and store them as koalas dataframe
2. create an empty dataframe with the structure of the final output
3. create a list with unique data from one of those tables
4. for element in this list a long sequence of transformations begins and I got one piece of the final output

so it got this form:

```
import koalas as pd

df1 = pd.read_parquet('link to mount')
df2 = pd.read_parquet('link to mount')
df3 = pd.read_parquet('link to mount')
df4 = pd.read_parquet('link to mount')

final_df = pd.DataFrame['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4']

list = df1.column.unique().tolist() #this list contains like 100 elements

for el in list:
    **lot of transformation that tooks 10/15 minute per element and results in final_df_el**
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, final_df_el])
```

for now  all the operation in  the for cicle are  executed in serie, i'd like to execute them in parallel. someone got a suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: maybe [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1) can help

Comment: @OfekGlick thank you but it's a pay to read article, i can't read it :(